# echo $JAVA_HOME returns blank in MacOS catalina despite having set it properly in zshrc

Tags: java, macos, version, zshrc

I a using the latest MacOS catalina(10.15.4) and using `.zshrc` for my profile as latest version of [mac deprecated the bash shell](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features), This is the follow-up question of [my previous unanswered question on not able to change the default java version to 1.8 using jenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017152/not-able-to-change-the-jdk-in-mac-os-using-jenv?noredirect=1#comment109693971_62017152).

When I was trying to debug more found my echo $JAVA_HOME always returns blank, despite having set it in following manner.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

And

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**Note i've sourced my `.zshrc` file after the change** but still no luck, although when I set on the terminal then it print the proper value but its only on that console(as expected).

Adding the content of my ~/.zshrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home
#export JAVA11_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
#export JAVA14_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v14)
#export RUNTIME_JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
#export PATH="/Users/java-dev/Library/Python/3.7/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
alias sr='source ~/.zshrc'
alias rt='cd /Users/java-dev/rt'
alias dev='cd /Users/java-dev/development'
alias code='cd /Users/java-dev/code'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not using bash anyway, despite deprecation? Please check what `echo $0` says.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca please see `echo $0
-zsh`

Comment: Did you run `source ~/.zshrc`? It's required to apply new changes to zshrc file.

Comment: @anquangman yes I am very well aware of that and do this all the time, thanks for confirming this :)

Answer (score 1):

The file name is changed in latest catalina OS . you need to create a file named **.zprofile** (same place where you have created .bash_profile file. This needs to be done because .bash_profile is now .zprofile) and place your export command over there.

If it already exists, please append your export command in the file like below.

export PATH=$your_path$:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=$your_path$

export M2_HOME=$your_path$

check this [macOS Catalina 10.15(beta) - Why is ~/.bash_profile not sourced by my shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784894/macos-catalina-10-15beta-why-is-bash-profile-not-sourced-by-my-shell)

Comment: there is no `.bash_profile` in my home dir also as I mentioned in my question I am already using `.zshrc` and other things like aliases are working fine, moreever I tried your commands on my terminal and after `export JAVA_HOME=$your_path$` if I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` it prints just `$`, can you try these commands

Comment: if it is not there, can you create one under /Users/(yourHomeDIr)/ with name .zprofile and set your java_home like below export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home (in the file)

Comment: I was facing similar issue and it got resolved once after I have created a file name .zprofile in my home dir. now java home and maven home echoes properly in any new terminal

Comment: it didn't work , also can you provide content of your .zprofile?

Comment: my username in the com is vijay. file is placed under /Users/vijay/.zprofile content is export PATH=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/mypath. did u try in new terminal post this file creation?