# .zshrc JAVA_HOME returning blank on new terminal but works when do source explicitly mac OS (catalina)

Tags: macos, zsh, java-home

This is in continuation of my previous two stack-overflow questions [echo $JAVA_HOME returns blank in MacOS catalina despite having set it properly in zshrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080159/echo-java-home-returns-blank-in-macos-catalina-despite-having-set-it-properly-i) and [Not able to change the JDK in Mac OS using Jenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017152/not-able-to-change-the-jdk-in-mac-os-using-jenv?noredirect=1#comment109693971_62017152) and looks like I found the issue.

Issue is that I am using .zsh and it works fine for aliases when I add a new alias but when I simply add `JAVA_HOME` as below line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

It doesn't work on the new terminal but when I explicitly do source `source ~/.zshrc` then it prints the value of `echo $JAVA_HOME` and thats the reason of issues mentioned in my previous questions.

**I've verified that `zsh` is my login shell as mentioned in several forums but still why content of `.zshrc` is not loaded in newly opened terminal?**

Comment: Not really related, but `.zprofile` is better for adding environment variables, as it can be inherited by a non-login interactive shell rather than having to redefined it in `.zshrc`.

Comment: That said, is your terminal emulator actually configured to start an instance of your login shell?

Comment: @chepner thanks for your valuable feedback, but I even tried mentioning this in .zprofile but with explicit source it was not working in the new terminal, can you guide me how to fix that and I am not sure how to check what you mentioned in your second comment.

Comment: @es-enthu : For debugging, I would place a `set -x` at the top of `.zshrc` to verify that this file is indeed sourced. It should be, because - unless you have modified the variable `ZDOTDIR` (check its value!)  - an **interactive** zsh is supposed to read `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`, and a shell attached to a terminal should certainly be interactive.

Comment: @es-enthu : Having said this, it does not matter what your **login** shell is, so for the safe side, verify that you are really running zsh, by doing a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`.

Comment: @user1934428 sorry for late reply `echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.7.1` return and echo $ZDOTDIR returns nothing.

Comment: And when you just open a subshell, by typing `zsh`, do you then see your .zshrc be executed (assuming you have put in a `set -x`, as I suggested)?

Comment: @user1934428 yes I see that when I use set -X

Comment: (I hope you mean `-x`, not `-X`). Well, this then means that this file is sourced. This means that you should be able to trace, why `JAVA_HOME` has not been set. Just compare each entry from the `-x` trace to each line in you `.zshrc`.

Comment: ok sure will do